# How to find the biggest m that a function is in O($h^m$)

Tags: limits

i try to find the biggest m that 
    $$f(h) = h^{-2}(\sin(1+h)-2\sin(1)+\sin(1-h))+\sin(1)$$
is $\in O(h^m)$ ($h \to 0, h > 0$)

I tried this:
    $$ f(h) = h^{-2} (((1+h)-\frac{(1+h)^3}{3!}+\frac{(1+h)^5}{5!} \mp ...) -2(1-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{5!} \mp...) + ((1-h)-\frac{(1-h)^3}{3!}+\frac{(1-h)^5}{5!} \mp ...))+(1-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{5!} \mp...) =h^{-2}(2(1-h)-\frac{(1+h)^3-(1-h)^3+2}{3!} + \frac{(1+h)^5-(1-h)^5-2}{5!} \mp  ...)+\sin(1)$$
But what now?

Can you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use the Taylor approximation around $1$,

$$f(1+h) = f(1) + f'(1)\cdot h + \frac{f''(1)}{2}h^2 + \frac{f'''(1)}{3!}h^3 + \dotsb$$

Use the similar approximation of $f(1-h)$ to obtain

$$f(1+h) + f(1-h) = 2\cdot f(1) + f''(1)\cdot h^2 + \dotsb$$

Use approximations of high enough order to achieve your goal.

Comment: What is approximation of high enough order?

Comment: Well, you divide by $h^2$, so the second order Taylor polynomial will not suffice. Try the next few orders until you get something of the form $c\cdot h^m$ with $c\neq 0$. You don't have to go far.

Comment: isn't the next: $$f(1+h) + f(1-h) = 2\cdot f(1) + f''(1)\cdot h^2 + \frac{2 \cdot f''''(1)}{4!} \cdot h^4$$ so i would get h^m m=2 by dividing with h^2?

Comment: isn't this term - 2*sin(1)  and then divided by $h^2$: $$f''(1)+\frac{2 \cdot f''''(1)}{4!} \cdot h^2 + \cdot \cdot \cdot$$

Comment: Right, the next Taylor approximation that produces a new term in $f(1+h) + f(1-h)$ is the fourth-order approximation, and you get what you wrote. After subtracting $2f(1)$ and dividing by $h^2$, you are left with $$f''(1) + \frac{f^{(4)}(1)}{12}h^2 + \sin 1 = \frac{f^{(4)}(1)}{12}h^2.$$

Comment: and thats $$ \frac{sin(1)}{12} * h^2$$ right? Does this mean, that its $O(h^2)$ because $ \frac{sin(1)}{12}$ is a constant in [0,1]

Comment: Exactly, that means it's $O(h^2)$. More, it's $\Theta(h^2)$. That $\dfrac{\sin(1)}{12} < 1$ is not important, what matters is that it's $\neq 0$.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help. =)